# Text inside a span element does not wrap within the width the parent p tag

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

I have this test page which I see the text gets wrapped around inside the Parent p element. But the problem I am having is that when I am trying to do the same thing in my web site, I only see the first line of the span tag and the rest of the text is hidden when they are beyond the width of the `P` element.

What should I look in the Chrome developer tool in order to troubleshoot my problem?

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p style="width: 120px;">
    <span>
                    Jellyfish or jellies[1] are softbodied, free-swimming aquatic animals with a gelatinous umbrella-shaped bell and trailing tentacles. The bell can pulsate to acquire propulsion and locomotion. The tentacles may be utilized to capture prey or defend against predators by emitting toxins in a painful sting. Jellyfish species are classified in the subphylum Medusozoa which makes up a major part of the phylum Cnidaria, although not all Medusozoa species are considered to be jellyfish.
                </span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to look at the word-wrap ban for tag `p` or `span`. `white-space: nowrap` or something similar.